# Unwanted NHibernate update command

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have the following classes

```
public class Contact
{
    public Contact() {
        Addresses = new List<Address>();
        EmailAddresses = new List<EmailAddress>();
        PhoneNumbers = new List<PhoneNumber>();
    }
    public virtual int ContactID { get; private set; }
    public virtual Firm Firm { get; set; }
    public virtual ContactType ContactType { get; set; }
    public virtual string FullName { get; set; }
    public virtual string FiscalCode { get; set; }
    public virtual string Notes { get; set; }
    public virtual ContactRole ContactRole { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Address> Addresses { get; private set; }
    public virtual IList<EmailAddress> EmailAddresses { get; private set; }
    public virtual IList<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; private set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public virtual int AddressID { get; private set; }
    public virtual string StreetAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public virtual string City { get; set; }
    public virtual Province Province { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
    public virtual AddressType AddressType { get; set; }
    public virtual bool PostalAddress { get; set; }
}
```

These classes have been mapped to the database using FluentNHibernate. These are the mapping classes

```
public ContactMap() {
    Table( "Contacts" );
    Id( c => c.ContactID ).Column( "ContactID" ).GeneratedBy.Identity();
    References( c => c.Firm ).Column( "FirmID" );
    References( c => c.ContactType ).Column( "ContactTypeID" );
    Map( c => c.FullName );
    Map( c => c.FiscalCode );
    Map( c => c.Notes );
    References( c => c.ContactRole ).Column( "ContactRoleID" );
    HasMany( c => c.Addresses ).Cascade.SaveUpdate();
    HasMany( c => c.EmailAddresses ).Cascade.SaveUpdate();
    HasMany( c => c.PhoneNumbers ).Cascade.SaveUpdate();
}


public AddressMap() {
    Table( "Addresses" );
    Id( a => a.AddressID ).Column( "AddressID" ).GeneratedBy.Identity();
    Map( a => a.StreetAddress );
    Map( a => a.ZipCode );
    Map( a => a.City );
    References( a => a.Province ).Column( "ProvinceID" );
    References( a => a.Country ).Column( "CountryID" );
    References( a => a.Contact ).Column( "ContactID" );
    References( a => a.AddressType ).Column( "AddressTypeID" );
    Map( a => a.PostalAddress );
}
```

I am trying to load a considerable amount of contacts inside the database using these classes. My code that create these object can be logically explained as follow

```
Create a contact
For each address of this contact 
    create an address
    set the contact address
    add the address to the contact collection
Next
For each email of this contact 
    create an email
    set the contact email
    add the email to the contact collection
Next
```

I have no problem with all the descendant collection like Email, PhoneNumber except that I have a problem with Address. In fact when I try to insert an contact that has at least one address I get the following error

```
Could not insert collection: [GSLConverter.Entities.Contact.Addresses#3551][SQL: UPDATE Addresses SET AuthorID = @p0 WHERE AddressID = @p1]
Invalid column name 'AuthorID'
```

Instead of using ContactID is using AuthorID. **Where does that AuthorID come from????**

These are the queries that NHibernate execute on the server

```
INSERT INTO Addresses (StreetAddress, ZipCode, City, PostalAddress, ProvinceID, CountryID, ContactID, AddressTypeID) VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7); 
select SCOPE_IDENTITY();
@p0 = 'xxx xxxxxx, 69 ', @p1 = '80142', @p2 = 'xxxxxx', @p3 = False, @p4 = 1, @p5 = 113, @p6 = 3632, @p7 = 1

UPDATE Addresses SET AuthorID = @p0 WHERE AddressID = @p1;
@p0 = 3632, @p1 = 26
```

**@Stefan Steinegger: this is the mapping of the class, the only one, that reference an AuthorID member**

```
public IssueNoteMap() {
    Table( "IssueNotes" );
    Id( ino => ino.IssueNoteID ).Column( "IssueNoteID" ).GeneratedBy.Identity();
    References( ino => ino.Issue ).Column( "IssueID" );
    Map( ino => ino.NoteDate );
    Map( ino => ino.NoteTitle );
    Map( ino => ino.NoteBody );
    References( ino => ino.Author ).Column( "AuthorID" );
}
```

The AuthorID field is a reference to the Contact table that have not be still mapped on the Contact side (as you can see from the previous Contact mapping

Comment: Is it possible that you have some conventions elsewhere that could be interfering? It sounds ridiculous to ask, but do you have an Author object that references Address? It is possible that if there is, a cascade could be trigger something unexpected due to the binding.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. I dont have any convention expressely setup. I have done a find on my classes and actually I have found an AuthorID field inside a class that is not, in any way, related to address and contact. Is there a way to view the mapping that FluentNHibernate is doing on the classes?

Comment: How does this mapping with the AuthorId look like?

Comment: I am going to edit the question to include it.

Comment: Do you have some many-to-many relation of a property called "Addresses"?

Comment: @Stefan: No. At least not in the part of the model that I am working to a that is related to Address and Contact. Anyway, As the other part of the model is not already completely mapped I have just commented out the property `Author` of the `IssueNote` class. Everything worked good. Now the question is: why that property was interfering with the Contact/Address classes even if was never instantiated and moreover did not have been mapped from the Contact side?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is `IssueNote.Author` by any chance a type of `Contact`?  If so, the `Fluent Mapping` of

```
References( ino => ino.Author ).Column( "AuthorID" );
```

is attempting to update your 'Addresses' table to ensure that it also has the `ContactId`stored in the Foreign Key of `AuthorId` which you have told it that `IssueNote.Author` uses when mapping to `Contact`s

You have told nHibernate this:

[image]

When you really want this:
[image]

So, change the IssueNoteMap to the following so that the ContactId is used to map the Author and it should work

```
References( ino => ino.Author ).Column( "ContactId" );
```

Comment: Wow!!! You are absolutely correct! I have just started working with NHibernate and, as I am too lazy when it comes to read manuals, I supposed that the `References` mapping would refer to the local side column. I have applied your suggestion and everything works. Thank you very much. One more question though: how did you make that diagrams? I mean, which tool did you use? Thanks again