# Help needed with FluentNHibernate mapping

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have the following entities

[image]

and I am trying to map them with help of FluentNHibernate.

Some notes about the entities:

- The attributes `CreatedBy` and `AssignedTo` on the `Task` entity are of type Person and, on the database side, are int columns called respectively `CreatorID` and `AssigneeID`
- The attribute `WrittenBy` on the entity `Note` is of type Person and it persist on the database on a column called `AuthorID`

I am not going to include all the mapping here as it is maybe not needed, but the biggest problem I am facing to came out when I have added the Task and the Note mapping.

Now in fact if I try to add an Address to a Person object NHibernate try to execute the following query

```
UPDATE Addresses SET AuthorID = @p0 WHERE AddressID = @p1;
```

Where am I wrong with this?

**EDIT**: Added the Mapping of the entities

```
public PersonMap() {
    Table( "Persons" );
    Id( c => c.PersonID ).Column( "PersonID" ).GeneratedBy.Identity();
    References( c => c.Company ).Column( "CompanyID" );
    HasMany( c => c.Addresses ).Cascade.SaveUpdate();
    HasMany( c => c.TasksAsCreator ).Cascade.SaveUpdate();
    HasMany( c => c.TasksAsAssignee ).Cascade.SaveUpdate();
    HasMany( c => c.NotesAsAuthor ).Cascade.SaveUpdate();
}

public TaskMap() {
    Table( "Tasks" );
    Id( i => i.TaskID ).Column( "TaskID" ).GeneratedBy.Identity();
    References( i => i.Company ).Column( "CompanyID" );
    References( i => i.CreatedBy ).Column( "CreatorID" );
    References( i => i.AssignedTo ).Column( "AssigneeID" );
    HasMany( i => i.Notes ).Cascade.SaveUpdate();
}

public NoteMap() {
    Table( "Notes" );
    Id( n => n.NoteID ).Column( "NoteID" ).GeneratedBy.Identity();
    References( n => n.Task ).Column( "TaskID" );
    References( n => n.WrittenBy ).Column( "AuthorID" );
}
```

**EDIT 2**: After exporting the mapping (thanks to dotjoe) I have found many strange results as the one that follow

```
<bag cascade="save-update" name="NotesAsAuthor" mutable="true">
  <key>
    <column name="CreatorID" />
  </key>
  <one-to-many class="Note, GSLConverter, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
</bag>
```

**This is completely wrong!** And does not reflect the mapping showed above....

Comment: Is this not this question again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138170/unwanted-nhibernate-update-command

Comment: Not properly the same but very similar. Can you help even on this one?

Comment: Could you please add the Notes mapping as you've stated this contains the `AuthorId`?

Comment: Done. Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: I want to say that this kind of error sometimes appear even on the relation between Person and Task with the fields CreatedBy and AssignedTo. It must be an error that I am doing on every mapping class... :(

Comment: It seems to be related to everytime you talk to a Person Class, but I'm not sure why. Maybe export the mapping as suggested by dotjoe and look for all places where you're written `AuthorId` and verify that they are correct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you show the mappings for properties related to the Person entity? I would make sure you specify the same fk column names on both sides (Reference and HasMany) of the Note/Task to Person mappings. I've seen this before...I think it's a bug in Fluent when it uses the previously specified column name for a type on another mapping. Also, make sure you have the latest version of Fluent.

To troubleshoot you can view the generated xml mappings with the `ExportTo` method of FluentMappingsContainer...

```
var factory = Fluently.Configure()
                .Mappings(mc =>
                    mc.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<PersonMap>().ExportTo("."))
                .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have edited my question as per your request.

Comment: what do you mean by `I would make sure you specify the same fk column names on both sides (Reference and HasMany) of the Note/Task to Person `? `HasMany` does not have a `Column()` method. Could you please give me a sample?

Comment: HasMany has the `ForeignKeyColumn()`...I believe it will default to "classname_id" if not specified. You should use the `ExportTo` method on the Fluent configuration to view the generated xml mapping files. Might help trouble shoot.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the export. Could you please hav ea look at my latest edit?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where Fluent nHibernate is getting the `CreatorID` column name from but according to [the docs](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping#HasMany_.2F_one-to-many) you can specify it using the method `KeyColumn`

```
HasMany( c => c.NotesAsAuthor ).KeyColumn("AuthorId").Cascade.SaveUpdate();
```

I don't have a test project in front of me, so give it a go and let me know if it works.

Comment: thanks! I just did it and was performing a test. It seems to work. I spent a lot of time as my model is pretty large. I really do not understand why it get so random if you dont specify the right column on both sides. Thanks again for your time :)